# How to wrap all text into unique span tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to wrap all body text(each word) into unique span tag.

**Before wrap** :

```
<body>    
<div>
  <p>word word </p>
  <div>word word</div>
    <ul>
        <li>word word</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <p>word word <strong>word</strong> </p>
</div>
</body>
```

**After wrap** :

```
<body>
<div>
    <p><span id="1">word</span> <span id="2">word</span> </p>
    <div><span id="3">word</span> <span id="4">word</span></div>
    <ul>
        <li><span id="5">word</span> <span id="6">word</span></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <p><span id="7">word</span> <span id="8">word</span> <strong><span id="9">word</span></strong> </p>
</div>
</body>
```

I tried this in jquery but it doesn't give what i expect

```
$('body *').each(function(){

        var words = $(this).text().split(" ");

            $(this).empty();
            $t=$(this);
            $.each(words, function(i, v) {
                $t.append('<span>'+v+'</span>');
            });

});
```

Thanks in advance,
Logan

Comment: performance-wise, you're unnecessarily caling $(this) 3 times, while you could've had your $t=$(this) on top and then reuse that $t later on

Comment: also, you're closing your unordered list twice (ul tag)

Comment: you can give id, $t.append('<span id="'+i+'">'+v+'</span>')

Comment: @amit `<span id="n'+i+'">'` better not to start with number\

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
(function (count) {
  'use strict';
  (function wrap(el) {
    $(el).contents().each(function () {
      // Node.* won't work in IE < 9, use `1`
      if (this.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        wrap(this);
      // and `3` respectively
      } else if (this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        var val = $.trim(this.nodeValue);
        if (val.length > 0) {
          $(this).replaceWith($.map(val.split(/\s+/), function (w) {
            return $('<span>', {id: count = count + 1, text: w}).get();
          }));
        }
      }
    });
  }('body'));
}(0));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LNLvg/3/

**update**: this version does not silently kill the whitspace ;)

```
(function (count) {
  'use strict';
  (function wrap(el) {
    $(el).filter(':not(script)').contents().each(function () {
      if (this.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        wrap(this);
      } else if (this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && !this.nodeValue.match(/^\s+$/m)) {
        $(this).replaceWith($.map(this.nodeValue.split(/(\S+)/), function (w) {
          return w.match(/^\s*$/) ? document.createTextNode(w) : $('<span>', {id: count = count + 1, text: w}).get();
        }));
      }
    });
  }('body'));
}(0));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mtmqR/1/

Comment: what is difference between ELEMENT_NODE AND TEXT_NODE, If I alert ELEMENT_NODE in what will it revert and what if I TEXT_NODE

Comment: @amit sorry, I don't quite get your question.

Comment: This seems to lose the spaces between the words and loses any leading or trailing spaces too.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's correct. Wasn't too sure if that's wanted or unwanted, For, with all those spans I guess CSS would be a solution if whitespace is wanted. Also I think the general usage is clear, keeping the whitespace is just a matter of how the *replacement function* is defined.

Comment: Whitespace can be very important for word wrapping and I don't think that can be simulated with CSS.  I mention this because in my solution in my answer, preserving the spaces and only the spaces that were originally there and putting them outside the spans was a meaningful amount of work.

Comment: @jfriend00 I included a second version which will keep the whitespace.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for except for one thing, how can I target an element to apply this algorithm on so it doesn't do it on every word in the html file.

I figure it's a matter of adapting `$(el).filter(':not(script)').contents().each(function () {` but I can't figure it out. Let's say I have a .content class and only want to run the script on that selector. How would I do this?

Comment: i turned this into a jquery plugin / npm package if anyone needs it https://www.npmjs.com/package/per-word-action

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using plain javascript that wraps the words in spans and preserves the spaces that were in the text, but leaves them outside the spans so only the words themselves are in the spans:

```
function splitWords(top) {
    var node = top.firstChild, words, newNode, idCntr = 1, skipChild;
    var re = /\S/;
    while(node && node != top) {
        skipChild = false;
        // if text node, check for our text
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            if (re.test(node.nodeValue)) {
                newNode = null;
                words = node.nodeValue.split(" ");
                for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    if (words[i] === "") {
                        newNode = document.createTextNode(" ");
                        node.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, node);
                    } else {
                        newNode = document.createElement("span");
                        newNode.id = "word" + idCntr++;
                        newNode.innerHTML = words[i];
                        node.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, node);
                        if (i < words.length - 1) {
                            newNode = document.createTextNode(" ");
                            node.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, node);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (newNode) {
                    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
                    node = newNode;
                    // don't go into the children of this node
                    skipChild = true;
                }
            }
        } else if (node.nodeType == 1) {
            if (node.tagName == "SCRIPT") {
                skipChild = true;
            }
        }        

        if (!skipChild && node.firstChild) {
            // if it has a child node, traverse down into children
            node = node.firstChild;
        } else if (node.nextSibling) {
            // if it has a sibling, go to the next sibling
            node = node.nextSibling;
        } else {
            // go up the parent chain until we find a parent that has a nextSibling
            // so we can keep going
            while ((node = node.parentNode) != top) {
                if (node.nextSibling) {
                    node = node.nextSibling;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3mms7/

FYI, I made the id values be "word1", "word2", etc... since before HTML5, id values were not allowed to start with a number.