# split all text inside dom element into <span>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to split all elements inside html DOM node into spans with ids, for example:

lets say I have element:

```
<div>
<h1>Header</h1>
<h2>header2</h2>
<p class="test">this is test p</p>
</div>
```

and the result should be:

```
<div>
<h1><span id="1">Header</span></h1>
<h2><span id="2">header2</span></h2>
<p class="test"><span id="3">this</span><span id="4">is</span><span id="5">test</span> <span id="6">p</span></p>
</div>
```

thanks for any help

it shoul also work if there are nested images for example:

```
<div>
<h1>Header</h1>
<h2>header2</h2>
<p class="test"><img alt="test alt" />this is test p</p>
</div>
```

and the result:

```
<div>
<h1><span id="1">Header</span></h1>
<h2><span id="2">header2</span></h2>
<p class="test"><img alt="test alt" /><span id="3">this</span><span id="4">is</span><span id="5">test</span> <span id="6">p</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: but "this is test p" is not four elements just one

Comment: What happens if the element is a `span` with a single word in it already?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/irehot/1/edit)*

To wrap each word something like this should help:

```
var c = 0;                                // create a counter
$('div > *').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).html().split(' '), // split your text strings
        len = text.length,                // get lenght of splitted parts
        result = [];                      // create array
    for( i=0; i<len; i++ ) {              // looping 'len' times....
        result[i] = '<span id="'+( ++c )+'">' + text[i] + '</span>';  // populate array
    }
    $(this).html(result.join(' '));       // apply edits
});
```

Comment: The only issue is this doesn't handle the inside of the p tag the way he mentioned it should.

Comment: `ind` will give the same IDs for every word in certain element.

Comment: $(this).html().split(' ') -> it doesnt work with nested elements for eample <p><img .../>this is p with nested img </p>

Comment: @gruber than try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105059/how-to-wrap-all-text-into-unique-span-tag

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = $('.test').text();
var result = "";
str = str.split(" ");
$.each(str,function() {
   result += '<span>' + this + '</span>';
});
$('.test').html($(result));
```